# how to send enum data types using call by refernce in C language

Tags: c, enums

```
typedef enum type {ERROR,SUCCESS,FAILURE}type;

fun( char a[50],  type *temp )
{....}
```

I want to send an empty temp value and this function should set the type in that variable address?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a `type` variable and pass the address of it:

```
type t;
char s[50];

fun(s, &t);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

 typedef enum  mytype {ERROR,SUCCESS,FAILURE}mytype;

fun( char a[50], enum mytype *temp )
{
    *temp=ERROR;
}

int main()
{
    mytype e=SUCCESS;
    printf("%d\n",e);
    enum type *p2 = &e;
    fun(NULL,p2);
    printf("%d\n",e);
}
```

Comment: Do consider selecting the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef enum type {
   ERROR,
   SUCCESS,
   FAILURE
}type ;

void foo (type *t, int* result)
{
  //*result = *t;  
  *result = FAILURE;
}

void main ()
{
  int a = -1;
  type t;
  //t = SUCCESS;
  foo (&t, &a);
}
```

enum =  series of #define , taken care at compile time, similar to preprocessor

Comment: -1, that explanation is very misleading, an enum is nothing at all like a series of `#define`, and not very "similar to preprocessor" at all.

Comment: @user35971: you might want to accept the answer

Comment: @unwind : I do understand that its misleading, I was trying to make the OP look at the concept, although I admit it was not very clever .. But an enum is indeed calculated at compile time ... right ?